# Centre align elements vertically with FlowLayout in jawa.awt

Tags: java, awt, layout-manager, flowlayout

Is there a way to center-align components vertically using the `FlowLayout` layout manager only? or would I need to use a different layout manager?

I have to give constant values of horizontal seperation to get elements on different lines, Is there a way to dynamically do it?

```
Frame frame = new Frame();
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,500,40)); // i have to give a constant value for horizontal separation here
frame.setSize(450,270);
frame.setVIsible(true);
```

What I want it to look like:

[image]

The complete main method of my program (if needed)

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException // frame is an instance varible
    {
        secure ob=new secure();
        Font font=new Font("SanSerif",Font.PLAIN,14);
        ob.frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,500,40));
        ob.frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent)
            {
               System.exit(0);
            }
         });
        Button b=new Button("Enter");
        TextField text = new TextField(10);
        ob.l.setSize(50,20);
        b.setSize(50,70);
        ob.frame.add(ob.l);
        ob.frame.add(text);
        ob.frame.add(b);
        ob.frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        ob.frame.setTitle("Password Check");
        ob.frame.setSize(450,270);
        ob.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        ob.frame.setVisible(true);
        text.setEchoChar('*');
        ob.l.setAlignment(Label.CENTER);
        ob.l.setFont(font);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
           {
                String pass1 = text.getText();
                pass1=pass1.trim();
                try
                {
                    ob.check(pass1);
                    text.setText("");
                }
                catch (Exception e1)
                {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
           }
        });
    }
```

I am new and have been researching on this for the past few days only, so may have missed out on essential information. Do correct me if I am wrong. :)

Comment: AFAIK you can not dynamically center components vertically using `FlowLayout`

Comment: ohk, thanks. Please do let me know if you get any more information. :)

Comment: A FlowLayout is designed to display components on a single line. It will wrap to the next line if there is not enough space on a single line. If you need components on separate lines then you should be using a different layout manager. Read the Swing tutorrial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Your question doesn't have enough information for us to suggest which layout manager, or combination of layout managers you should use. If you need more help then you need to post an image or drawing of what you want the layout to be.

Comment: This could *probably* be done using a `GridBagLayout` but like @camickr I'm not entirely sure I understand how you intend this GUI to appear initially, or when made bigger. If you can provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of both situations, that would help a lot.

Comment: ok, so `FlowLayout` only works for a single horizontal line, right...? @camickr  @Andrew Thompson

I have added what I want it to look like and also the main method of my program... do I need to add anything else..?

Comment: 1) you've been given a link to the Swing tutorial on layout managers. 2) The GridBagLayout has been suggested. Start there. Also, that is NOT Swing code. Swing components start with "J".

Comment: ohhk, so I should start with Swing first... thanks :)

Comment: *"I should start with Swing first"* As far as components go, definitely. Note that Swing is built on AWT, it extends & uses many of its classes (e.g. the AWT layouts), but for components, stick with Swing.

Comment: BTW - given the GUI is a password check, I'd put a `JPasswordField` (one of a variety of Swing components for which there is no AWT equivalent) into a `JOptionPane` (which is another Swing only class). If this might work for you, let me know and I'll do a simple example.

Comment: A `JOptionPane` based login might [look something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMSEU.png).

Comment: ohhh, thnx for the tips :)

Comment: Actually I thought since Swing was based on older AWT features... I should start with those awt components first... 